# Facing valueerror when trying to write scraped data to csv

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the urls in the url list and then write it down into a csv. It works fine if I just scrape the first two links:

```
"21Shares Bitcoin ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abtc',
"21Shares Ethereum ETP":'https://21shares.com/product/aeth/'
```

However when I add all the other links I get the Error below:

ValueError: Length of values (16) does not match length of index (17)

I can't figure out where the problem lies and how I can solve it. What needs to be changed in order for my code to be able to scrape through all links and then store the data in a csv?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date


class sharesWebscrapping:
    today = date.today()

    dict_words = {'<span class="value">': "",
                  '<span class="value value-up">': "",
                  '</span>': "",
                  ',': "",
                  '$': "",
                  '<div class="value"><div>': "",
                  '<div>': "",
                  '</div>': "",
                  '<div class="value"><!-- -->': "",
                  '<span class="value value-down">':""

                  }

    index_name = ["AUM",
                  "Securities Outstanding",
                  "NAV per Unit",
                  "Daily Change",
                  "VALOR",
                  "Fee",
                  "SEDOL",
                  "ISIN",
                  "Reuters",
                  "Issuer",
                  "WKN",
                  "iNAV",
                  "Bloomberg",
                  "Custody",
                  "Market Maker",
                  "Authorized Participants",
                  "Collateral Agent"

                  ]

    url = {"21Shares Bitcoin ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abtc',
            "21Shares Ethereum ETP":'https://21shares.com/product/aeth/',
            "21Shares Bitcoin Cash ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abch',
            "21Shares Cardano ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/aada',
            "21Shares Aave ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/aave',
            "21Shares Bitcoin Suisse Index ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abba',
            "21Shares Bitcoin Cash ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abch',
            "21Shares Binance BNB ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/abnb',
            "21Shares Polkadot ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/adot',
            "21Shares FTX Token ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/aftt',
            "21Shares Algorand ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/algo',
            "21Shares Crypto Mid-Cap Index ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/alts',
            "21Shares Solana ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/asol',
            "21Shares Cosmos ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/atom',
            "21Shares Uniswap ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/auni',
            "21Shares Avalanche ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/avax',
            "21Shares Stellar ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/axlm',
            "21Shares Ripple XRP ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/axrp',
            "21Shares Tezos ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/axtz',
            "21Shares Crypto Basket Index ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/hodl',
            "21Shares Crypto Basket Equal Weight ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/hodlv',
            "21Shares Crypto Basket 10 ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/hodlx',
            "21Shares Bitwise Select 10 ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/keys',
            "21Shares Chainlink ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/link',
            "21Shares Terra ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/luna',
            "21Shares Decentraland ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/mana',
            "21Shares Sygnum Platform Winners Index ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/moon',
            "21Shares Polygon ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/poly',
            "21Shares Short Bitcoin ETP": 'https://21shares.com/product/sbtc'

           }

    data = pd.DataFrame(index=index_name, columns=url)

    for key in url:

        print("Downloading " + key + "...")

        response = requests.get(url[key])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        list_value = list(soup.findAll(class_="value"))
        new_list_value = []
        for i in list_value:
            new_list_value.append(str(i))

        data[key] = new_list_value

        data.replace(dict_words, inplace=True, regex=True)

    data.to_csv(r"/Users/a/documents" + str(today) + ".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `columns=` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you should be passing `url` through the `data=` argument.:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index=index_name, data=url)
```

Even simpler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(url, index=index_name)  # Since data is the first argument
```